# How to make list item selectable in Input Tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a InputFilter. Here is my code.

```
MyFilter = function(args) {
    var dataUrl = args.url;
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);
    //var input = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">';
    var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">' +
        '<ul id="myUL">' + '<li>' + '<a href="#"></a>' + '</li>' + '</ul>';
    div.innerHTML = myTable;

    function foo(callback) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json", true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }

    foo(function(data) {
        debugger;
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_opt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < jsonc.length; i++) {
            new_opt += '<li><a href="#">' + jsonc[i]['VALUE'] + '</a></li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = new_opt;

    });

    myFunction = function() {
        debugger;
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want when i click on list item, these items geteselected and displayed into inputfield,like combo box.

Can anybody please help me how to do that.

Here is my fiddler. [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Arsenal/wsfgbqyk/)

**Note** : Currently with my code I am able to search, I want to select and display in input.

It is happening in other project but there I am using table.

Code for that is

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)').forEach(function(_tr) {
            _tr.addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.getElementById('myInput').value += " ; " + this.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].textContent;
            });
        });
```

I want to click on items of `a` tag and selected items want to display in input tag by `;` separation.

Comment: define `Inputfield`...

Comment: @vsync I mean It is input Tag where I can give some input.

Comment: the title is very unclear. you if posted an illustration of what you want to happen in terms of UX it would have helped

Comment: @vsync I changed. Hope It is better.

Comment: unclear what you're asking: `I want to select and display in input`. select how? in what way? describe the flow of things.

Comment: @vsync I updated my question

Comment: answered, hope it's what you wanted since it was really not very clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/wsfgbqyk/2/)

```js
function filterList(value, list) {
    var li, i, match;
    
    for (i = list.children.length; i--; ) {
        li = list.children[i];
        match = li.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        li.classList.toggle('hidden', !match)
    }
}

function selectItem(input, value){
 input.value = value;
}


var input = document.querySelector('input'),
 list = document.querySelector("#myUL");

input.addEventListener('input', function(e){
 filterList(e.target.value, list);
})
list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 if( e.target.tagName == 'A' && !e.target.classList.contains('header') )
  selectItem( input, e.target.textContent )
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li.hidden{ display:none; }

#myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks It works, For multiple selection I created I am using `input.value += value;` Well One quick question is it possible to show and hide li on click of input tag.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question.. click on the input where? what will it show or hide? you don't explain

Comment: Right now list is showing just below the input tag. I want to show only on click of input tag.

Comment: you could have used [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).. for that you need to open a separate question or google it..

Comment: OK, Thanks I will try to make as a datalist

Comment: @David - [Here you go](https://jsfiddle.net/wsfgbqyk/4/) it shows the list when the input has any value

Comment: Here I need one small help. `filterList` This is not happening if already one data is selected. Suppose If I select one data then type other character filterrarion is not happen. Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gb81fujv/. Can you please help me in this. Also any idea so I can go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

using jquery you can set selected name fill in `textfield`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
$('a').click(function() {
  var val = $(this).text();
  $('#myInput').val(val);
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without using jquery. Because it is happening in other project where I am using table. Different css I am using. I updated my question. Please check

Comment: Do you know How to give JSON data to JS fiddle. I will create a fiddle of working code.

Comment: sorry but i have not use jsfiddle

Comment: Ok let me figure out the way to pass code to you, both working or not working. ty

Comment: without `jquery` you will have to write onclick function on each `<a>` tag